# Why is my mongo collection being wiped on azure ubuntu instance?

Tags: mongodb, azure, ubuntu

I'm using azure ubuntu instance to store some data every minute in a mongo database. I noticed that the data is being wiped approximately once a day. I'm wondering why my data is being wiped?

I have a log every minute that shows a count of the db. Here are two consecutive minutes that show all records are deleted

```
**************************************
update at utc: 2022-08-06 10:19:02.393351 local: 2022-08-06 20:19:02.393366
count after insert = 1745
**************************************
update at utc: 2022-08-06 10:20:01.643487 local: 2022-08-06 20:20:01.643544
count after insert = 1
**************************************
```

You can see the data is wiped as count after insert goes from 1745 to 1. **My question is why is my data being wiped?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Data was being deleted in a ransom attack. I wasn't using a mongo password as originally I was only testing mongo locally. Then when I set the bindIp to 0.0.0.0 for remote access, it meant anyone can access if they guess the host (this is pretty dumb of me).

Always secure the server with a password especially if your bindIp is 0.0.0.0. For instructions see https://www.mongodb.com/features/mongodb-authentication

---

#### More Detail

To check if you have been ransom attacked, look for a ransom note. An extra database may appear see `show dbs` in my case the new db with ransom note was called "READ__ME_TO_RECOVER_YOUR_DATA"

> All your data is a backed up. You must pay 0.05 BTC to 1Kz6v4B5CawcnL8jrUvHsvzQv5Yq4fbsSv 48 hours for recover it. After 48 hours expiration we will leaked and exposed all your data. In case of refusal to pay, we will contact the General Data Protection Regulation, GDPR and notify them that you store user data in an open form and is not safe. Under the rules of the law, you face a heavy fine or arrest and your base dump will be dropped from our server! You can buy bitcoin here, does not take much time to buy https://localbitcoins.com or https://buy.moonpay.io/ After paying write to me in the mail with your DB IP: rambler+1c6l@onionmail.org and/or mariadb@mailnesia.com and you will receive a link to download your database dump.

Another way to check for suspicious activity is in Mongodb service logs in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log. For other systems the filename might be mongodb.log. For me there are a series of commands around the attack time in the log, the first of which reads:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-07T09:54:37.779+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20337,   "ctx":"conn30393","msg":"dropDatabase - starting","attr":
{"db":"READ__ME_TO_RECOVER_YOUR_DATA"}}
```

the command drops the database or starts dropping the db. As suspected there are no commands to read any data which means the attacker isn't backing up as they claim. Unfortunately someone actually payed this scammer earlier this month. https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/65d035ca4db759a73bd9cb68610e04742ffe0e0b71ecdf88f54c7e464ee80a51